# Error when running a Gradle task in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

Using Eclipse, windows 10, JDK1.8.0_191 , and JRE1.8.0.191.   Here's the error:

```
Caused by: : Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251"
```

`JAVA_HOME` in my windows variables is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191`, which is what it should be.

Comment: The error message says that the java-home variable is set to your jre not your jdk, check again if this is the problem.  Maybe you have got two java_home variables, one for the user and one for the system. Then the user one is used.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

I found a workable solution, which isn't proposed or listed anywhere else, so posting it if anyone else can be helped by it in the future.

Within the Gradle Tasks window, right-click the project and open the run configuration.  Goto project settings and click "override project settings".  This opens the JAVA home field.  Just change the variable there to point where you want and it works.